# React loop with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to grab a todo and add it to an object of todos, can you tell me what's the problem here?

Newbie in React.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

function Content() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("") // todo: user input
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState({}) // todos: object

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setTodos({ ...todo, todos })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      <form>
        <input onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Add Todo Here" />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
      </form>
      {console.log(todos)}
      {todos.map((todo) => todo)}
    </>
  )
}

export default Content
```

Comment: Please describe the issue you are having or the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function Content() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState("") // todo: user input
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]) // todos: object

  function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setTodos([ ...todos, todo ])
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Todos</h1>
      <form>
        <input onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Add Todo Here" />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
      </form>
      {console.log(todos)}
      {todos.map((todo) => todo)}
    </>
  )
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Content />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You've mixed todos and todo.. You were trying to spread todo which is a string not an array.

and also, you've not set array right. it should be [] not {}.
:)

here's a code sandbox with a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-cerf-soxii

here's the diff between your code and mine:
https://www.diffchecker.com/nBReZt19